# How to throttle events RX?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am trying to throttle an event being triggered by a slider when the value has been changed I would like to throttle to 1 seconds,  its Print every second but the data being printed is incorrect all value in the collection is being printed at the same time but I would like to print the last value of that Unique data type every second, result posted below.

[Fully reproducible code]
XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtbilly" Text="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0,0,0,382" ></TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtbob" Text="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0,162,0,233" ></TextBox>
    <Slider x:Name="slbilly"  Value="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0,57,0,306" GotMouseCapture="slbilly_GotMouseCapture"/>
    <Slider x:Name="slbob"  Value="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0,206,0,171" GotMouseCapture="slbob_GotMouseCapture" />
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Student billy = new Student("Unique1", 0.0f);
    Student Bob = new Student("Unique2", 0.0f);
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtbilly.DataContext = billy;
        slbilly.DataContext = billy;
        billy.PropertyChanged += Students_PropertyChanged;

        txtbob.DataContext = Bob;
        slbob.DataContext = Bob;
        Bob.PropertyChanged += Students_PropertyChanged;

    }
    static IList<Student> studentsList = new List<Student>();
    IObservable<Student> observable;
    private void Students_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var student = (Student)sender;
        studentsList.Add(student);
        Debug.Print("List COunt ==>>>" + studentsList.Count.ToString() + "\n");

        observable = studentsList.ToObservable(Scheduler.Default);

        observable.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), Scheduler.Default);
    }

    private void slbilly_GotMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        observable?.Subscribe(i => Debug.Print("{0}\nPos {1}\n Time Received {2}\nOBS Count{3}", i?.ID?.ToString(), i.Position.ToString(), DateTime.Now.ToString(), observable.Count<Student>().ToString()));
    }


    private void slbob_GotMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        observable?.Subscribe(i => Debug.Print("{0}\nPos {1}\n Time Received {2}\nOBS Count{3}", i?.ID?.ToString(), i.Position.ToString(), DateTime.Now.ToString(), observable.Count<Student>().ToString()));
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Student : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _ID;
    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return _ID;
        }
        set
        {
            _ID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ID"));
        }
    }
    private float _Position;
    public float Position
    {
        get
        {
            return _Position;
        }
        set
        {
            _Position = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Position"));
        }
    }
    public Student(string id, float position)
    {

        this.Position = position;
        this.ID = id;

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

> 1. Unique1 Pos 0.06468305  Time Received 18/04/2022 00:16:05
> 2. Unique1 Pos 0.06468305  Time Received 18/04/2022 00:16:05 OBS
> 3. Unique1 Pos 0.06468305  Time Received 18/04/2022 00:16:05 OBS
> 4. Unique1 Pos 0.06468305  Time Received 18/04/2022 00:16:05 OBS
> 5. Unique1  Pos 0.06468305  Time Received 18/04/2022 00:16:05 OBS

Expected: If the user starts at 0.0 and drag from 0.0 to 300.98 in 1 seconds, then to 200.45 by 2 seconds:

> Unique1 Pos 0.0  Time Received 18/04/2022 00:16:05
>
> Unique1 Pos 300.98  Time Received 18/04/2022 00:16:06
>
> Unique1 Pos 200.45  Time Received 18/04/2022 00:16:07

Issues:

1. `studentsList` counts keeps growing and not reset by the observable(Every time the use release the mouse from the control it should reset the list.
2. InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.'
3. The Debug.Print only gets printed/execute once I release the mouse from the drag motion

@Enigmativity answer sorted my forth known issue.

I am new to the Rx technology so I am not sure if I am implementing it in the correct manner.

**Basically if the Value changed is coming from the same control I would like to throttle it, e.g. on the slider control when the user click the knob to drag start throttling once the user releases the mouse click stop throttling**

Comment: Are you expecting the observable to fire every time you add an item to the list?

Comment: @Enigmativity Not sure what you mean by the observable firing every time I add to the observable, I am making an Http request(Debug.Print) to update my student position on a live output window so every time I drag the Slider to move the student I would like the student to move/ update every second instead of sending allot of commands, uncontrollable. When I drag, the command to update the position live, the value changed is sending lots of micro command instead I would like to send the Last value every 1 seconds.

Comment: I specifically said "list", not "observable".

Comment: @Enigmativity ok, Apologies, no the Debug.Print should only execute at a constant rate. Not even sure if the list is needed trial and error at this point, My aim is to get the Last value of a specific control value, and print it every interval

Comment: Then why are you building the observable from `studentsList`? I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Are you trying to update the `Position` property using the slider?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, I am  trying to update the Position property using the slider. And every time the property changes it needs to print/make an http call, The http call is expensive so I would like to control the amount of request

Comment: That's easy. I'll post an answer when I have time. You're a way off, at the moment, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an attempt to show you what you probably need to get your observable to work, it should look something like this:

```
var observable =
    Observable
        .Merge(
            Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>(h => billy.PropertyChanged += h, h => billy.PropertyChanged += h).Select(x => billy),
            Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>(h => Bob.PropertyChanged += h, h => Bob.PropertyChanged += h).Select(x => Bob))
        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0))
        .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
        .Do(s =>
        {
            studentsList.Add(s);
            Debug.Print($"List Count ==>>>{studentsList.Count}{Environment.NewLine}");
        })
        .Select(s => Observable.FromAsync(() => ExpensiveHttpCall(s)).Select(u => new { Student = s, Result = u }))
        .Switch();
```

And the subscription, like this:

```
_subscription =
    observable
    .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
        .Subscribe(x =>
        {
            Debug.Print($"{x.Student.ID}{Environment.NewLine}Pos {x.Student.Position}{Environment.NewLine}Time Received {DateTime.Now.ToString()}{Environment.NewLine}List Count{studentsList.Count()}");
        });
```

I added this code to simulate a long-running HTTP call:

```
    private async Task<Unit> ExpensiveHttpCall(Student student)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0));
        return Unit.Default;
    }
```

Now I don't know exactly what you're trying to do with this query, but this should help to move you in the right direction.

Key to Rx is to try to get your query down to one single query that you subscribe to once. It makes life much easier.

Here's the complete code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Student billy = new Student("Unique1", 0.0f);
    Student Bob = new Student("Unique2", 0.0f);
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtbilly.DataContext = billy;
        slbilly.DataContext = billy;

        txtbob.DataContext = Bob;
        slbob.DataContext = Bob;

        var observable =
            Observable
                .Merge(
                    Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>(h => billy.PropertyChanged += h, h => billy.PropertyChanged += h).Select(x => billy),
                    Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>(h => Bob.PropertyChanged += h, h => Bob.PropertyChanged += h).Select(x => Bob))
                .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0))
                .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
                .Do(s =>
                {
                    studentsList.Add(s);
                    Debug.Print($"List Count ==>>>{studentsList.Count}{Environment.NewLine}");
                })
                .Select(s => Observable.FromAsync(() => ExpensiveHttpCall(s)).Select(u => new { Student = s, Result = u }))
                .Switch();

        _subscription =
            observable
            .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
                .Subscribe(x =>
                {
                    Debug.Print($"{x.Student.ID}{Environment.NewLine}Pos {x.Student.Position}{Environment.NewLine}Time Received {DateTime.Now.ToString()}{Environment.NewLine}List Count{studentsList.Count()}");
                });
    }

    private IDisposable? _subscription = null;

    private async Task<Unit> ExpensiveHttpCall(Student student)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0));
        return Unit.Default;
    }

    static IList<Student> studentsList = new List<Student>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  `Debug.Print($"{x.Student.ID}...` does not execute until I release the drag motion I would like it to execute while its dragging. And  is there a way to use the existing handler `private void Students_PropertyChanged` ? instead of `Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventHandler,`...` because I can potentially have 100s of these controls.

Comment: @Dev - Your code has two students. So I set up the observable from the two students. If you have a list of students you can set it up easily - `_studentsList.ToObservable().Select(student => Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>(h => student.PropertyChanged += h, h => student.PropertyChanged += h)).Merge();`

Comment: "does not execute until I release the drag motion I would like it to execute while its dragging" Could this be because its on the UI thread? SynchronizationContext.Current

Comment: @Dev - Yes, but because you were doing the `studentsList.Add(s)` I wanted to make sure it happened on a single thread. I don't know why you're doing `studentsList.Add(s)` - that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I don't need it :), As I mention I was doing trail and error, I came across RX for the first time seems very powerful and readable, its something ill go off and learn to the best of my ability.

Comment: @Dev - It is very powerful. It's very much worth learning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244049/discussion-between-dev-and-enigmativity).

Comment: I have Removed  `studentsList` as I don't need it, `Debug.Print($"{x.Student.ID}{Environment.NewLine}` is still getting executed only when I release the Knob, was hoping it print during the drag

Answer (score 2):

You have the line:

```
observable.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), Scheduler.Default);
```

It should be:

```
observable = observable.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), Scheduler.Default);
```

The operators in Rx are fluent. You get a new observable from the `Throttle` operator. Without the assignment `observable` stays the same.

Comment: I have made the changes above and it got rid of the duplicate data, The `Debug.Print` only gets printed/execute once I release the mouse from the drag motion, `studentsList` keeps growing, it should reset once I release the mouse  and I am getting this error sometimes `InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.'` I would like for even when I am still dragging the time still ticks and execute once every 1 sec constantly. My aim is, when the user is dragging the slider instead of Printing thousands of time I want to print constantly every interval