# How to run RX queries on background thread

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am trying to throttle a slider but it only prints when I stop scrolling from the duration(5 seconds) I would like for the Data to be printed to the console while the user is scrolling every interval(5 seconds).

How can I get the throttle to work during the scrolling movement? So if the user drags constantly it for 20 seconds it should print at 5 , 10, 15 and 20 seconds

Original question [How to throttle events RX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71906258/3558639).

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Student billy = new Student("Unique1", 0.0f);
    Student Bob = new Student("Unique2", 0.0f);
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtbilly.DataContext = billy;
        slbilly.DataContext = billy;

        txtbob.DataContext = Bob;
        slbob.DataContext = Bob;

        var observable =
            Observable
                .Merge(
                    Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>(h => billy.PropertyChanged += h, h => billy.PropertyChanged += h).Select(x => billy),
                    Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>(h => Bob.PropertyChanged += h, h => Bob.PropertyChanged += h).Select(x => Bob))
                .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0))
                .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
                .Do(s =>
                {
                    Debug.Print($"List Count ==>>>{0}{Environment.NewLine}");
                })
                .Select(s => Observable.FromAsync(() => ExpensiveHttpCall(s)).Select(u => new { Student = s, Result = u }))
                .Switch();

        _subscription =
            observable
            .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
                .Subscribe(x =>
                {
                    Debug.Print($"{x.Student.ID}{Environment.NewLine}Pos {x.Student.Position}{Environment.NewLine}Time Received {DateTime.Now.ToString()}{Environment.NewLine}List Count{0}");
                });
    }

    private IDisposable? _subscription = null;

    private async Task<Unit> ExpensiveHttpCall(Student student)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0));
        return Unit.Default;
    }

}
```

Comment: The behaviour you're seeing is exactly how `Throttle` is meant to work. Perhaps you want `Sample` instead?

Comment: Or perhaps the more complicated `.GroupByUntil(x => Unit.Default, x => x, x => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0)))`.